# How to convert TPC to TPT with existing data in ef migration?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have 2 tables named "Tickets" and "Toys". These are 2 different **tables with data**.

```
    [Table("Toy")]
public class Toy
{
    public int ToyId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Size{ get; set; }
}

[Table("Ticket")]
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketId{ get; set; }
    public int Type{ get; set; }
    public int Amount{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}

public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

But now I decided to implement TPT inheritance, such that I will have a table named "Product" width an "Id" column which will be identity. Now 2 classes,"Ticket" and "Toys" should be inherited from "Product". But I get lots of errors when try to update database.

```
public abstract class Product
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public long Price{ get; set; }
 }

[Table("Toys")]
public class Toys: Product
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Size{ get; set; }
}

[Table("Ticket")]
public class Ticket: Product
{
    public int Type{ get; set; }
    public int Amount{ get; set; }
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}

public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

In theory I know, I should:

1. inherit from product,
2. Set identity insert on in "Product"
3. Copy all data to "Product"
4. Set identity insert off in "Product"
   But it still has errors on dropping PKs and dropping indexes and Nothings updates.

Comment: Migrations will never be able to do this because it involves too many manual conversion steps. I think you better do it by hand and start a new migration from that point. By the way, the steps you describe look more like TPH.

Comment: Other infos in addition to Gert Arnold answer. With TPH you will also need to remove the Table attribute from Ticket and Toy (or Toys) and during migration you will also need to update the Discrimitator column of Products table.

Answer (score 0):

The code first implementation here looks good.  Try and reset the entity frame implementation.  This [link](http://www.mortenanderson.net/reset-entity-framework-migrations) has great instructions.